# Can you add a separate discussion site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, subjective, trolling

Sometimes you just want to let out some steam, and troll about some technology or software. You are not looking for any answers, but for users with similar experiences and interesting stories. So why not create a separate discussion site (trolling.stackoverflow.com?), where you could ask questions like "why do you hate technology X" or "What are the stupidest bugs you encountered in X"?

Comment: @gnat: I don't see the connection here; the other question asks for automatic penalties for those who close something as subjective, this asks for a new site just for subjective questions. There is a dupe here somewhere, but that is not it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay, retracted my vote

Comment: @gnat: Yeah, sorta. I seem to recall one with better answers. I don't really care much about this one being closed as a dupe of the one you suggest though.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff

Answer (score 9):

They're called blogs.

Comment: [In some circles](http://xkcd.com/148/), they are known as blags

Answer (score 7):

Go create it with http://stackexchange.com

I bet it'd really work! Really really!

Answer (score 3):

http://reddit.com/r/programming

Answer (score 1):

I thought that's what usenet is for.

Answer (score 1):

Against it, certainly as an attached site like SU, SF, etc.  Last thing we need is someone getting butthurt because someone trolled on .NET and seeking things to downvote on the sister sites.  If it doesn't help to build the community, then it really doesn't have any place.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `troll` tag on Meta that only shows if you favorite it.  Troll questions can't be marked as duplicate, can't be closed, and are invisible to everyone except the troll team.

That way it'll be just a steam vent.

Comment: Why don't you use IRC or Google Wave instead?

Comment: too complicated...

Comment: +1 might be difficult to implement though

Comment: They'd probably also have to be CW by default to prevent people from making the rep cap off of rants against script kiddies.

Comment: A great idea really!