# Accept question of type "What is the best..." on any other sibling site, not necessarily Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

I highly think that question of type "What is the best..." bring a lots of useful information to people. Perhaps it should not be accepted in Stack Overflow, I agree.

But I would really appreciate to have access to a site where I could ask those kind of questions. Ideally, the site will have a similar well tuned awards system as Stack Overflow. Also it would be nice if that site would have a very nice popularity as Stack Overflow. For each user on that site, just beside its reputation could be displayed the reputation from Stack Overflow (without being able to affect it) if it exists, that way it could help to evaluate the quality of an answer.

To add some considerations (explanations) to my suggestion, I invite you to read one of my really not popular question at meta.stackoverflow.com: [Questions of Type: "What is the best..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192461/question-of-type-what-is-the-best-why-not-where-to-go)

Sorry I just discover http://area51.stackexchange.com/ as Emrakul told me. You can close this, I can't ! In "Contact us" they do not mention how to send suggestions.

If anybody can close that, I would appreciate. Sorry to disturb !

FYI: Please take a look the fourth in the most voted questions on StackOverflow (not subjective ???) !!! And I would be surprise to see all others that are deleted :-) !

Comment: hahahhah gave you an upvote for persistence, are you sure we're not related ;) - ps think it's a bad idea.. as it's too open ended and can result in a lot of opinions and less facts

Comment: Personally, I don't believe any Stack Exchange website is formatted to correctly facilitate debates of any kind. It's designed for Q&A, it makes sense for Q&A, and discussions do have their place in other locations

Comment: This isn't so much a "feature request", but a "new web platform suggestion".

Comment: You are free to suggest this on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/); if you garner the support you need, then the team will _consider_ launching the site.

Comment: @ Emrakul, I was looking for that site very much !!! Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks !

Comment: Some people recommend [slant.co](http://www.slant.co/) for what you're proposing.

Comment: So you want people throwing around unsupported opinions about unanswerable questions and voting based on popularity rather than correctness... There's already a [website out there](https://www.facebook.com/) that you might want to try.

Comment: @joran ... Hey thanks a lot, I will take a look, sounds good !

Comment: @Skippy - It happen between 1-3 times a year that I need those kind of information. It is invaluable to me. It could save me months of work if I choose the right product at first. StackOverflow already saved me that time on few products but it sounds like it will not anymore.

Comment: Nice find, @gnat! This suggestion has come up a couple of times in the past month and I knew there had to be a master question, but I couldn't track it down.

Comment: @JoshCaswell pay it forward by dupe-closing the question [where I learned about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32769/can-you-add-a-separate-discussion-site#comment587877_32769). :) I can't do that myself because of retracted vote (ironically, retraction was about _wrong_ dupe)

Comment: Vote cast, @gnat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with these is that people can get into some serious arguments about what the best type of something is. That is the main reason we don't like those sorts of questions.

If people could be civil and agree to disagree, then these questions wouldn't be a problem. But maturity often fails humanity, so we resort to the disallowal of these questions

Comment: I disagree!!!!!! Take your gloves off, outside now!!!! hahahahah

Comment: I agree with you for StackOverflow if it is not part of its vision for that site. But it would be of non measurable usefulness to have that kind of site with properties I described.

Comment: @EricOuellet Give me an example of a question where you feel has no potential for disagreement?

Comment: You really think the reason that list questions aren't allowed is because we've come to the conclusion that _all_ SE members are incapable of rational, professional disagreement? That's not at all true. The problem is simply that questions whose answers are primarily opinion-based generate too many _valid_ responses for the Q&A format to handle helpfully. It's the obverse of the problem with asking a concrete and circumscribed technical question in a forum -- the medium just doesn't support it well enough.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I didn't say every single member would be incapable

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself this question - *why* do I wish there was a Stack Exchange site that allowed those questions?

I suspect it's because you've come to rely on SE sites for answering a large proportion of your technical questions. Partly this is because the SE results are always well placed in Google, something caused partly by great SEO but mostly because the format is ideal for Google searching: question and answer. Not question and debate.

The natural instinct is to extend SE sites to cover all manner of discussion and debate, much like [all software expands to eventually read mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Zawinski.27s_law_of_software_envelopment). But doing so would ruin the fundamental principles that have led the site to be so successful and popular in the first place.

Comment: I agree. I was just searching a way to have a site very like StackOverflow that enable me to ask subjective questions and I did not know about ara51.

Comment: Area 51 is not a site for asking subjective questions, and proposing a site to do so there is unlikely to be successful IMO. There's always Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Jamie's law may need updating. The bloody BIOS on my wife's laptop not only reads mail, but includes a *web browser*. WTF?

Comment: @Wooble, I think that they will loose a good opportunity but I'm not totally sure about its success. Only time will tell us... when one site like that will exists... (I know about Area 51)