# Where to ask a computer-hardware/science history/societal impact question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question/start a discussion about the development of computer hardware and software and their impact on society from a historical point of view and I am kind of lost in the wealth that is the StackExchange network. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you add a separate discussion site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32769/can-you-add-a-separate-discussion-site)

Comment: That doesn't even come close to being a duplicate @gnat.

Comment: @Yannis did you read the opening sentence of the question here? "I want to... start a discussion..."

Comment: @gnat Yes, I've read both questions. And I feel that voting to close a well meaning site recommendation question as a duplicate of a tangentially related question that asks for "trolling.stackoverflow.com" is very poor form. Questions are duplicates when they ask the same thing. Not when they happen to have some words in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not discussions forums. We strongly prefer specific questions over open ended discussions, and discussion-y questions often get closed quickly. If starting a discussion is what you're after, I'm afraid you'll have to look elsewhere.

That said, the good folks at [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) and [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) will probably be able to answer your specific questions, if you have them. Please take care to check out their help articles and look through their existing questions to see what kind of questions they welcome.

Comment: Programmers also has a [history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, with some extremely interesting questions about software development history. However, history questions have always been controversial on the site, and it's not always easy to get them right.

Comment: thanks! Pointing out the Q&A character certainly clarified things!